# Snowflake Service Account for Azure storage access

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to [Snowflake Doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-azure-config.html#step-2-grant-snowflake-access-to-the-storage-locations) for Azure:

> 2. Click the Accept button. **This action allows the Azure service principal created for your Snowflake account** to obtain an access token on any resource inside your tenant.

A Storage Integration requires a Service Principal to access data

Do you know how the service principal creation is managed ?

Is there a different and unique Snowflake service principal per account ? the same is valid for Reader/Managed Accounts or sub Accounts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the service principal is per account basis and it follows the same principal as for other Security objects in Snowflake.